# Error with clean and build in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, build

I was coding on another PC and recently had to transfer all my projects to a new one (with a different username if it is worth mentioning). I made some progress on one of projects and tried to clean and build there is an error occurring:

`C:\Users\Renobatio\Documents\NetBeansProjects\GUI\nbproject\build-impl.xml:262: C:\Users\Renobatio\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MigLayout\miglayout-swing.jar is not a directory.`

I don't know why miglayout is referenced. On the previous PC I tried to use miglayout, but it wasn't working for me so I removed it completely and then I could clean and build on that PC, but now I can't. Specifically, line 262 says:

`<javac debug="@{debug}" deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" destdir="@{destdir}" encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" fork="${javac.fork}" includeantruntime="false" includes="@{includes}" source="${javac.source}" sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" srcdir="@{srcdir}" target="${javac.target}" tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}" >`.

I tried to change the Vendor name on the projects properties but it didn't solve my problem.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I've ran across a similar issue when changing locations myself. After a few hours of banging my face into the keyboard I gave up and essentially recreated the project.

1) Created a new project using the same name as the original project
2) Setup the project properties mirroring the original's (run vars, libraries, ect...)
3) Close NetBeans
4) Copy the src folder from the original project to the newly created project folder.
5) Restarted NetBeans

It will rebuild according to its newly detected source & fix any of the xml issues. I know this isn't an ideal solution, but it worked for me.